# Aspxgridview focused row

Tags: c#, webforms, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have a page splited in two, on the left side with an aspxgridview and on the right side I have a few controls, aspxtextbox, aspx combo box...

The purpose is that when a line is chosen from the grid, the right side is populated with data obtained from an sql query.

Everything works fine using the focusedrowchanged event.

The problem is when the page first loads it doesn't populate the right side, because when it fires rhe focusedrowchanged event it retrieves an empty row using the focused row index.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I believe if you're wanting code to run *OnLoad* , then you will need to have a `_Load` event. It would be *very* helpful if you posted the relevant code that you are having issues with, along with your desired outcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the grid FocusedRowIndex and retrieve a related row Key values.

You check how exact the same approach works in [this](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/Rows/FocusedRow.aspx) online demo.